# Golang is not able to parse miliseconds if there is a comma?

Tags: date, go

here is an example how is the date looking from the data I'd like to parse:

```
2017-10-20 13:32:26,890
```

and my format look like this:

```
2006-01-02 15:04:05,000
```

now the weird part:

```
date := "2017-10-20 13:32:26,890"
_, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05,000", date)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

if I run this I am getting this error:

```
panic: parsing time "2017-10-20 13:32:26,890" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05,000": cannot parse "890" as ",000"
```

If I change the comma to a single dot in both the date and the format it's working properly. I can replace the comma with regexp, but why is this happening?

Comment: The parser just accepts only period as the ms separator, can't change that via the format string AFAIK.

Comment: The behaviour is documented as such: "A fractional second is represented by adding a period and zeros to the end of the seconds section of layout string, as in "15:04:05.000" to format a time stamp with millisecond precision. " If you're interested why the package authors decided so, you may want to visit the mailing list.

Comment: [golang.org/src/time/format.go](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go), I see only `case '.'` regarding the fractional seconds. Line: `249`

Comment: thanks, I replaced the comma

Comment: Looks like there is a bug already filed for handling comma in the time format. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6189

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed with `f02a26be` [1] (2021-03-15). Quoting from new docs [2]:

> Either a comma or decimal point followed by one or more nines represents a
> fractional second, printed to the given number of decimal places, with trailing
> zeros removed.

1. https://github.com/golang/go/commit/f02a26be
2. https://tip.golang.org/pkg/time#pkg-constants

Comment: Penny seems like it did not make it to 1.16.4 https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=milestone%3AGo1.16.4+label%3ACherryPickApproved :(

Comment: Seems like it is going to be in 1.17, not in 1.16 patches.